# htaccess redirect multiple domains to specific language .html

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have multiple domains I want to do the redirect.
Domains:

- domains.de
- domains.fr
- domains.my
- domain.uk

I want to setup redirect these domains to

- domains.de -> https://www.domains.de/de.html
- domains.fr -> https://www.domains.fr/fr.html
- domains.my -> https://www.domains.my/my.html
- domain.uk -> https://www.domain.uk/uk.html

Thank for you answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Raahul Is there a better way to combine all the domains

```
RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domains.(de|fr|my|uk)$
            RewriteRule ^$ https://www.domains.de/(de|fr|my|uk).html [L,R=301]
```

can it work this way?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domains.de$
            RewriteRule ^$ https://www.domains.de/de.html [L,R=301]
```

[Refer Links to write .htaccess](https://my.bluehost.com/hosting/help/htaccess_redirect)